# Typescript: Importing and Exporting by value or reference

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, express, export

I am converting some Javascript code over to Typescript and I am getting stuck on a basic import and Export:

Desired Functionality:
I want to be able to import 'POST_Requirements' in several other files. Each file that makes a call to POST_Requirements.ORGANIZATION() receives a new instance POST_Requirements stored a desired variable. Any editing of this instance does not effect other instances within the file or any outside file.

Actual Functionality:
any file that calls POST_Requirements.ORGANIZATION() does receive a new instance. However, if file X edits its instance, the instance in file Y experiences the same edit. Very confused because this would have been prevented by using "new"

EXPORTED CLASS: post.requirements.ts

```
export class POST_Requirements {
  readonly text_fieldnames: Array<string>;
  constructor(
    file_fieldnames: Array<string>,
    text_fieldnames: Array<string>,
    max_file_size: number = 25 * MEGABYTE,
    max_fieldname_size: number = 200,
    max_field_size: number = KILOBYTE
  ) {
    this.file_fieldnames = file_fieldnames;
    this.text_fieldnames = text_fieldnames;
    this.max_file_size = max_file_size;
    this.max_fieldname_size = max_fieldname_size;
    this.max_field_size = max_field_size;
  }

  static ORGANIZATION(): POST_Requirements {
    return new POST_Requirements(
      ORGANIZATION_FILE_FIELDNAMES,
      ORGANIZATION_TEXT_FIELDNAMES
    );
  }
}
```

Separate file:

```
let a: POST_Requirements = POST_Requirements.ORGANIZATION();
let b: POST_Requirements = POST_Requirements.ORGANIZATION();

let a_sub: Array<string> = a.text_fieldnames;
let b_sub: Array<string> = b.text_fieldnames;

console.log(a_sub)
console.log(b_sub)
a_sub.reverse();
console.log(a_sub)
console.log(b_sub)
```

a_sub and b_sub always print the same value. In a separate file, c_sub prints the same

Any insight as to why this is acting this way will be greatly appreciated

Comment: The instances are independent, but they share (by reference) the same arrays that you pass to the constructor, so when you mutate these arrays (by calling `reverse` for example) all these arrays are changed. You may make a copy of array in constructor or before passing it to constructor.

Comment: Yes that was it! This had me stuck for over an hour, I love you.

Answer (score 0):

You can use object cloning to make sure they are pointing to different objects

```
static ORGANIZATION(): POST_Requirements{
  let a = new POST_Requirements(["f1", "f2"], ["t1", "t2"]);
    return {...a}
}
```

Here is a stackblitz using angular as an example 
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-wxvgus